# google play libraries not working on emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, emulation, android-maps

Hello friends I am building an android app in which user selects two points on map and the app calculates the distance between those two points. But for some reason app is not showing any map in emulator and the app crashes on the real device. Have done all the things like imported google play library linked I to project but no success any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes you use Android v > 4.1.

After you start the emulator, download & install the following packages:

1. com.android.vending
2. com.google.android.gms

using the `adb install <APK FILE>` command on your terminal.

Use [this website](http://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/) to search and download the latest apks. After the installation is finished you should be able to run google maps.
(see also http://nemanjakovacevic.net/blog/english/2012/12/06/how-to-make-android-google-maps-v2-work-in-android-emulator/)

Comment: This is a great answer! Surprising there was no upvotes. I gave a +1 just now! I looked at your profile and saw you committed to the Protein Modeling proposal on Area51. Sorry that it didn't succeed. I proposed a [Materials Modeling](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=NzE1MWZiMjg1NmE1MDU4YWQ2ODkzMzZiNGY5OTRkNWRhN2JkNzdhZGUwODllOWUxNGNjZjRhZjBmYTE3M2M4ZBljSouiYXUzpNjPv6N_DNmpFSwSGHCb4w8-XBwHc-_E0) site which covers protein modeling, but also other materials like solar cells, photo-voltaics, energy storage materials, new developments in batteries,

Comment: and lighter or stronger materials for cars, airplanes, spaceships, etc. It would be very lovely to have you in the Private Beta! Please commit if you don't think it would be inconvenient!